# Query Check Status from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query

```
select * from user_profile
```

Now i want to add where condition check user status from other table (users)

```
select * from user_profile,users where users.status!=0
```

Please Do Not Recommend Join  i following old join query

Thanks

Comment: what is the foreign key in `users` table?

Comment: Add sample data and expected results

Comment: What do you mean "Please do not recomment join"? That's exactly what joins are for....

Comment: @RadimBača, foreign keys are not needed to join tables, their main purpose is to ensure data consistency (at insert, update, delete.)

Comment: @jarlh he clearly wanted to join according to the primary and foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use join, you have to use a subquery. I guess both tables have a column like `userId`:

```
select * from user_profile where userId in (select userId from users where status != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using `sub query`

```
select * from user_profile where status!=(select status from users where id =? or status=?)
```

what you compare `id or status` in `subquery`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a relation column (say `user_id` or perhaps `profile_id` or something -- not sure until you share sample data as requested.) between the two tables, you can join the two table and filter the rows like this:

```
select *
from user_profile p
join users u on p.user_id = u.user_id
where u.status != 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want every column from both tables in your query, you can use:

```
SELECT * from user_profile, users WHERE user_profile.user_id = users.id AND users.status! = 0
```

Where I assumed you have some column(like user_id - user_profile
and id - users in my example) that links both tables together.